# Jquery / Javascript execute, but do nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, refresh, toggle, slidetoggle

I'm executing an JavaScript/Jquery, but it doesn't nothing.

This is my Code:

```
        function ocultaGrid(idPanel) {
            var idPnl = '#' + idPanel

            $(idPnl).toggle();

            alert("BATMAN");
        }
```

The alert runs okay, but the toggle not.

here I call this JS:

```
Panel panelGrid = new Panel();
panelGrid.ID = "panel_grid" + i;

LinkButton lkBtn = new LinkButton();
lkBtn.ID = "link_button" + i;
lkBtn.Text = "+";
lkBtn.Attributes["onClick"] = "javascript:return ocultaGrid('" + panelGrid.ID + "'), false";
```

PS.: Jquery version 1.7.2

Any idea, why it's not working?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is the idPanel displaying the right name? Does that element exist?

Comment: Yes, I've debugged it, and it looks like okay.

Comment: What is the id of the panelGrid?

Comment: Is the second block c# code? If so, shouldn't you be passing panelGrid.ClientID?

Comment: I paste the Client ID, it is dynamic

Comment: Welcome to .NET - don't use an ID. .NET wants to hog them all, use a CSS class name instead.

Comment: I got this changing >> " var idPnl = '#' + idPanel "  TO >> " var idPnl = "'[id$=" + idPanel + "]'"; "